# How to push other data to new the column in cosmosdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-spatial-anchors

From spatial anchor sample (AnchorPoster.java) Now it only push anchorid to the cosmos db.  How i can push other data to the new column? this i my current code located in AnchorPoster in sample, but the cp1 cp2, cp3 are combined with anchorid.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... input) {
    return postAnchor(input[0],input[1],input[2],input[3]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (anchorPostedCallback != null) {
        anchorPostedCallback.accept(result);
    }
}

private String postAnchor(String anchor,String CP1, String CP2, String CP3) {
    String ret;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(baseAddress);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(anchor);
        output.writeBytes(CP1);
        output.writeBytes(CP2);
        output.writeBytes(CP3);
```

Comment: May I know what sample document you have referred over here?

Comment: I think you're trying to use the [SharingServiceSample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/tree/master/Sharing/SharingServiceSample) from the Azure Spatial Anchors sample repo. That service is written to only read the anchor id as a string from the app. If this is what you want to change, you're going to want to look into ASP.NET Core Web APIs to learn how to adjust the server side to fit your needs.